# high CPU usage of MySQL and recommendation from Mysqltunner

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, central-processing-unit

we have noticed that our database server is getting so high CPU (more than 90 % used by mysqld process), the output of mysqltunner is shown below, can you help me please,

i'm okay about the innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=7), but is there some other suggestions ?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the complete output from mysqltuner as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: all information are listed in the screenshots from mysqltuner, do you need further infos ?

Comment: It has to be text so that it is readable.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

That has two parts -- one is a deeper dive into the settings on your machine.  The other is capturing the slowlog.

High CPU almost always means poor indexing and/or poor formulation of queries.  The slowlog is a very efficient way to find the "worst" queries.  Then we can discuss how to improve them.

Tuner...

- The number of instances is not worth changing.
- 7G for the buffer_pool is *too big* for a 7.8G machine.  Limit it to about 70% of RAM; let's say 5G.
- Was MySQL swapping?  That is terrible for performance (but won't show up as high CPU).

Comment: Thanks for your response, the slow query logs file list about 59781 lines of queries, what do you think, the problem more related to indexing queries... or to hardware resources : RAM

Comment: Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the 59781 lines; then study the first few.  I prefer to improve indexes and/or formulation in preference to adding RAM.

Comment: this is the first time i heard about this tool : pt-query-digest, i google it, but i didn't find what i'm looking for, this tool will just have read access of logs right  ? it is safe to use ?

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ - https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html  -- Download the "Percona toolkit"; it is one of the tools.  If you are running on Windows, send me the slowlog; I can get it to run.

Comment: The tool does need access to the slowlog file.  If you are running on a cloud, look in the UI for a way to download the log.  It may also include ways to turn on logging.

Comment: yes, i'm trying now to download the file to a test machine so I can test that without installing the percona toolkit in the database server, thank you so much